# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to upload a file and store it in an uploads folder, but I get this error: `no such file or directory`
I get the message success in console but I get this error anyway.

```
POST /auth/register 500 21.023 ms - 260
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open E:\IMPORTANT\INFO-DEV\DEV\ANGULAR NODEJS\API AUTH\uploads\1671534381494.jpeg
```

**Here is my configuration code for upload.**

```
const path = require("path");
const multer = require("multer");
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "uploads/");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    const extension = path.extname(file.originalname);
    cb(null, Date.now() + extension);
  },
});
const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  fileFilter: function (req, file, callback) {
    if (
      file.mimetype == "image/png" ||
      file.mimetype == "image/jpg" ||
      file.mimetype == "image/jpeg"
    ) {
      callback(null, true);
      console.log("Image téléchargé avec succès"); // success message
    } else {
      callback(null, false);
      console.log("Seulement du fichier de type png, jpg ou jpeg"); // error message
    }
  },
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 2,
  },
});

module.exports = upload;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same error, but I was able to solve it by getting my current path.

```js
import multer from "multer";

// Set up multer storage options
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    console.log(" ~ file: upload.ts:11 ~ file", process.cwd());
    cb(null, `${process.cwd()}/src/Images`);
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + "-" + Date.now());
  },
});

// Create a multer instance with the storage options
const upload = multer({ storage });
export default upload;
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that your `uploads` folder doesn't exist or you set the path incorrectly.

I don't know where exactly you created `uploads` folder (and if you created it at all).

So in the destination param you should pass either:

`path.join(__dirname, '/uploads')` - in case that folder is in the same location where current js file is located.

Or `path.join(process.cwd(), '/uploads')` - in case if uploads folder is in the root of the project (where you run `npm start` etc.)

So, in short words you need to make sure folder exists and then make sure the path is correct.

P.S.
Using `../../` syntax should also work, you can try `../uploads` or `../../uploads` if, for example, that folder is on higher levels of your folders structure.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
As you said so well, I just created an uploads folder and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

you can try your path name as like

```
img: {
  data: fs.readFileSync(
    path.join(__dirname + "../../uploads" + req.file.filename)
  ),
  contentType: "image/png",
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

cb(null, './uploads/');

this line
 `cb(null, "uploads/");`

or try
 `cb(__dirname, "uploads/");`

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I just created an uploads folder manually before running the query (with postman) and it worked.